# How to convert timestap to hours and minutes in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, timestamp

I want to count how many hours and minutes between two timestamp which are generated by `Date.parse`. After I get the difference, I need to convert it into hours and minutes like `2.10` (means, 2 hours and 10 minutes). Once I have read that to do it you need to divide it with 3600 so I tried this code but it just gives me `0.89` instead of `1.26`.

```
var now = new Date();
var endTime = Date.parse(now)/1000;
var startTime = Date.parse("2018-03-16 10:29:17")/1000;

$scope.timestamp_difference = startTime - endTime;
$scope.hours = $scope.timestamp_difference/3600;
```

How to do it right?

Comment: You can use moment js for that

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't heard, Momentjs makes working with dates and times pretty damn easy in javascript i updated code for you may hope it will helps you now

```
var date1 = moment('03/15/2018 11:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm'),
   date2 = moment('03/16/2018 10:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm');

 var duration = moment.duration(date2.diff(date1));
//you will get 23 hours 00 minute
  alert(duration.asHours().toFixed(2))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dp7rzmw5/9771/

```
  Output: 23:00 hrs
```

Comment: sorry, that's not what I'm looking for. I just want to get how many hours the difference

Comment: Check output format it's in hh:mm just pass your timestamp difference between two timestamp in  unix(difference here)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTimeDifference(timestampDifference) {
    var hours = ~~(timestampDifference / 3600);
    var minuts = ~~((timestampDifference - hours * 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = timestampDifference - hours * 3600 - minuts * 60;
    return hours + '.' + minuts + '.' + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(timestampDifference / 60);
//  get minutes
var seconds = "0" + Math.floor(timestampDifference - minutes * 60);
// get seconds
var hour = "0" + Math.floor(timestampDifference / 3600);
//get hour
if ( hour > 1 ) { 
    return hour.substr(-2) + ":" + minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);
} else {
    return minutes.substr(-2) + ":" + seconds.substr(-2);
}
// check if the hour is greater then 1 than return time with hour else return minutes.
```